# Hovering on chart not aligned with mouse pointer javascript highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, highcharts

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

URL OF THE GIF OF THE ISSUE -> https://gfycat.com/selfishpitifuldunnart

As you can see in the image mouse pointer which is the black dot is far away from the crosshair/tooltip, I have tried all possible options I am aware of even tried updating library from V6.0.4 to V8.1.2 but couldn't get it to work. Any help appreciated. Thanks. Below is the code I am using to initialize the chart with.

```js
var avgTempChartingOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'avgTemperatureChartPanelChart',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',
        mapNavigation: {
            enableMouseWheelZoom: true
        },
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        events: {
            setExtremes: syncExtremes
        },
    },
    yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#ccd6eb',
    },
    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true,
        followPointer: false,
        // positioner: function() {
        //     return {
        //         x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
        //         y: -1 // align to title
        //     };
        // },
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            tooltip: {
                followPointer: true
            }
        },
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        series: {
            // stacking: 'normal',
            // cursor: pointer,
            animation: true,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            boostThreshold: 100 // number of points in one series, when reaching this number, boost.js module will be used
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        sourceWidth: 1200,
        sourceHeight: 800,
    },
    series: []
};
```

Comment: Please create codepen with the issue.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Hey guys, just solved it. It was because of the zoom css applied on the html body. When I removed it started working fine